# Python filtering: only keep most recent python MacPort

Tags: python, vim

I have a file open in Vim:

```
py24-sqlalchemy
py25-beautifulsoup
py25-beautifulsoup4
py25-bpython
py25-epydoc
py25-icalendar
py25-ipython
py25-libgmail
py25-mechanize
py25-numpy
py25-pil
py25-simplejson
py25-sphinx
py25-sqlalchemy
py25-sqlite
py25-tkinter
py25-vobject
py26-appscript
py26-beautifulsoup
py26-bpython
py26-epydoc
py26-game
py26-icalendar
py26-ipython
py26-mechanize
py26-numpy
py26-pdfminer
py26-simplejson
py26-sphinx
py26-sqlalchemy
py26-sqlite
py26-tkinter
py26-vobject
py27-appscript
py27-asciitable
py27-asciitable
py27-beautifulsoup
py27-beautifulsoup4
py27-blist
py27-bpython
py27-chm
py27-configobj
py27-dateutil
py27-epydoc
py27-game
py27-gdal
py27-gtk
py27-ipython
py27-lxml
py27-matplotlib
py27-mechanize
py27-mysql
py27-numpy
py27-pdfminer
py27-pil
py27-prettytable
py27-progressbar
py27-psutil
py27-py2app
py27-pylint
py27-pyobjc
py27-pyobjc-cocoa
py27-pypdf
py27-pyqt4
py27-simplejson
py27-sphinx
py27-sqlalchemy
py27-sqlite
py27-termcolor
py27-tkinter
py27-tz
py27-wxpython
py31-appscript
py31-asciitable
py31-beautifulsoup4
py31-blist
py31-bpython
py31-game
py31-lxml
py31-psutil
py32-asciitable
py32-beautifulsoup4
py32-blist
py32-bpython
py32-game
py32-ipython
py32-lxml
py32-psutil
# ... etc ... (many lines)
```

I want to filter lines so that, for Python versions in the 2.x range, I only keep the most recent package.

Example: if the file contains both py25-ipython and py26-ipython, I would like py25-ipython to disappear and py26-ipython to stay. Always keeping the latest version only, and always just one version per package.

Here is what I came up with but it's horribly coded. Looks like C64-BASIC code to me, almost.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import sys
import re

PATTERN_PYTHON_MACPORT = '^py(2[4567])-(\w[-\w]*)$'
REGEX_PYTHON_MACPORT = re.compile(PATTERN_PYTHON_MACPORT)

def main():
  packages = {}
  filtered_lines = []
  for line in sys.stdin:
    match = REGEX_PYTHON_MACPORT.match(line)
    if match:
      python_version = int(match.group(1))
      package_name = match.group(2)
      if package_name in packages:
        packages[package_name].append(python_version)
      else:
        packages[package_name] = [python_version]
    else:
      filtered_lines.append(line)
  for package_name in packages:
    versions = packages[package_name]
    if len(versions) == 1:
      version_to_keep = versions[0]
    else:
      version_to_keep = sorted(versions, reverse=True)[0]
      filtered_lines.append('py{}-{}\n'.format(version_to_keep,
                                               package_name))
  for line in sorted(filtered_lines):
    sys.stdout.write(line)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

How can I make this more Pythonic? Would this be easier to do in Vimscript? I would probably prefer a solution in Vimscript..

I am a beginner in both Python and Vimscript, by the way. Here to learn. Code examples would be great.

PS I run the filter from inside Vim with `:'<,'>! /Users/tinosino/Desktop/pyfilter.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the same (assuming your input list in already ordered). Otherwise, use `sorted(sys.stdin)`. And if you don't you to keep the Python 3.x modules, drop the 'else' clause.

```
import re
rex = re.compile('py2\d+-(\S+)')
modules = {}
for line in sys.stdin:
    match = rex.match(line)
    if match:
        modules[match.group(1)] = match.group(0)
    else:
        modules[line] = line
print '\n'.join(sorted(modules.values()))
```

Output:

```
py25-libgmail
py26-icalendar
py26-vobject
py27-appscript
py27-asciitable
py27-beautifulsoup
py27-beautifulsoup4
py27-blist
py27-bpython
py27-chm
py27-configobj
py27-dateutil
py27-epydoc
py27-game
py27-gdal
py27-gtk
py27-ipython
py27-lxml
py27-matplotlib
py27-mechanize
py27-mysql
py27-numpy
py27-pdfminer
py27-pil
py27-prettytable
py27-progressbar
py27-psutil
py27-py2app
py27-pylint
py27-pyobjc
py27-pyobjc-cocoa
py27-pypdf
py27-pyqt4
py27-simplejson
py27-sphinx
py27-sqlalchemy
py27-sqlite
py27-termcolor
py27-tkinter
py27-tz
py27-wxpython
py31-appscript
py31-asciitable
py31-beautifulsoup4
py31-blist
py31-bpython
py31-game
py31-lxml
py31-psutil
py32-asciitable
py32-beautifulsoup4
py32-blist
py32-bpython
py32-game
py32-ipython
py32-lxml
py32-psutil
```

Comment: Whoa, that's compact! So, you are using the property of stdin being sorted to replace the only value in the dict with the full package name as you scan the lines with the "highest" version, if I understand correctly. This obviously means filtering out py3.x versions before too.. I like `\S` instead of \w "+" -, that's a nice thing to learn.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Python 3.x is filtered out by the regular expression. This is why I added the 'else' clause in the loop (if you want to keep them). If you don't, drop the 'else' clause and the output will only have Python 2.x packages.

Comment: What I was doing, which was wasteful, was to keep a list of all versions seen rather than just keeping the highest. Anything else which was conceptually wrong?

Comment: Not really. You can avoid patterns like `if package_name in packages:  packages[package_name].append(python_version) else: packages[package_name] = [python_version]` by using a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict): `packages = defaultdict(list)` and then `packages[package_name].append` directly.

Comment: What a fantastic discovery this `defaultdict(list)`, thanks!! Accepting the answer and bowing in gratitude! `m(_)m`